# Multiple values in laravel post form (dropdown)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good day fellow programmers,

I have been frustrated all day because I have to make a submit form for an hour register app I have to create for the company I'm an intern at.

So basically what has to be done: I have made a submit form with multiple values, I got asked to make a dropdown selection in which I can put the values of "company name" and "task name". (tasks are connected to the company name). So basically what i'm wondering is how I can put 2 values in one dropdown menu. Having the layout of "$company name - $task name"

create.blade.php

```
     {!! Form::open(['url' => 'hoursregistrations/create','files'=>true]) !!}

            <div class="form-group" hidden>
                {!! Form::label('user_id', 'User ID: ') !!}
                {!! Form::text('user_id', $authenticated, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <select name="">
            @foreach($items as $item)
                <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
                    {{ $item->company->name }} - {{ $item->name }}
                </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('note', 'Notitie: ') !!} 
                {!! Form::text('note', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('date', 'Datum: ') !!}
                {!! Form::date('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('hours', 'Uren: (uren-minuten) ') !!}
                {!! Form::time('hours', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('hoursregistrations.index') }}">
                        @lang('button.cancel')
                    </a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                        @lang('button.save')
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

In this code snippet the company variable is $project_id and the task id is $subproject_id.

Also the controller function to redirect the data to the create view

```
    /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $authenticated = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
    $activity_name = Subproject::pluck('id');
    $items = array(
            'company_name' => Company::where('status','client')->pluck('company_name', 'id'),
            'subproject_id' => Subproject::pluck('title', 'id')
        );
        //dd($items);

    return view('hoursregistrations.create', compact('subproject_id', 'authenticated', 
        'company_name', 'activity_name', 'items'));
}
```

Conclusion: How can I combine the $project_id and $subproject_id into ONE dropdown item.

p.s I'm sorry if it sounds vague I am bad at explaining things

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use The Form Facade? Although this may not be helpfull to you, you can write it as plain HTML with Blade's Syntax:

```
<select name="">
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        <option value="{{ $task->id }}">
            {{ $task->company->name }} - {{ $task->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I don't have to use it as far as I know. Yet again, I'm a complete newbie at Laravel but I learned alot using tutorials. The point is that everything works the way it does now. The only thing is that I have to put 2 values in the facade form just the way you typed it.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add. I tried your method aswell but everything became messy and everything went AWOL

Comment: Can you provide the specific Code you're using in order to show the tasks right now, where you want to add the Company name and task name?

Comment: $items = array(
    'company_name' => Company::where('status','client')->pluck('company_name', 'id'),
    'subproject_id' => Subproject::pluck('title', 'id')
   );
   //dd($items);

Comment: That's where I pick up the data from the tables in the database. I dd'd(); the $items and it has the required values stored inside. My question is, how can I put the values of both items in one dropdown menu

Comment: Whats the name of your variable on the view? Also `$items`?

Comment: Sorry for me not understanding, and yes $items can be called in the view

Comment: I literally just did a dump die to confirm. And yes the data is stored within $items

Comment: Uhm, how are Companies related to Subprojects? And where are the tasks coming from? is as Task a subproject?

Comment: Yes, $subproject_id = the given tasks linked to $company_name.

Comment: Don't judge me for it, I'm not the one who linked all the stuff together (even I think it's quite weird but hey, i'm just an intern)

Comment: I tried to implement the piece of code you provided, only downside it $tasks is not implemented in the controller so I cannot call it in the view

Comment: I've edited my code according to your example. You want to loop through all tasks an show every task as an `<option>`. To get the name you want to take the task, fetch it's related company and get the name of the company, thus `$task->company->name`. I hope you get the idea. It's a bit odd because I don't know all of your variable names.

Comment: I changed the variable name to $items as $item, yet Trying to get property of non-object error comes up.

Comment: Can you please edit your quesition with all information needed in order for us to help you? So how Task is related to company and vice-versa (you can see that in thei respective Model PHP files.)

Comment: I'll edit my question so you can see the used php files for this feud. Hopefully that will give you a more in depth view of the situation